# JQuery Columnizer creating duplicate content on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, multiple-columns, window-resize

I am trying to create an article view for a blog using the JQuery Columnizer plugin (http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) to auto column-ize and paginate my content.  Here is a JSFiddle of my work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/opanitch/YY9x3/1/

The basic HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="page_template"><!-- Begin Paginate Template -->
        <div class='content'></div>
    </div><!-- End Paginate Template -->
    <div class="page">
        <div id="articleHeading">
            <p class="articleReturn"><a href="#">&laquo; Back to Newsroom</a></p>
                <h2 class="articleTitle">Article Title</h2>
                <p class="articleSubTitle">Subtitle</p>
                <div class="newsHR"></div>
                <div class="articlePic"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="articleContainer">
                <div id="articleBody">                        
                    <p class="articleCopy">
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus luctus dictum felis id ultrices. Etiam nisi augue, porttitor ac rhoncus non, vulputate eget elit. Donec mollis justo in mauris lobortis semper. Fusce eleifend cursus tincidunt. Vivamus vitae nibh ante, a vestibulum elit. Pellentesque id varius mi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacus lectus, porttitor eget eleifend at, eleifend eget urna. Maecenas in urna lobortis nisl facilisis tempus sed non ante. Sed in eros egestas magna posuere auctor eu ac nisl.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="articleNav">
                <p id="prevArticle" class="articlePagination"><a href="#">&laquo; Previous page</a></p>
                <p id="nextArticle" class="articlePagination"><a href="#">Next page &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am using the plugin's example pagination to achieve my fluid columns/pages via this JQuery call:

```
function buildNewsletter() {
    if($('#articleBody').contents().length > 0) {
        // when we need to add a new page, use a jq object for a template
        // or use a long HTML string, whatever your preference
        $page = $(".page_template:first").clone().addClass("newsPost").css("display", "block");

        // fun stuff, like adding page numbers to the footer
        $("#articleContainer").append($page);

        // here is the columnizer magic
        $('#articleBody').columnize({
             columns: 2,
             target: ".newsPost:last .content",
             overflow: {
                  height: pageHeight,
                  id: "#articleBody",
                  doneFunc: function(){
                       console.log("done with page");
                       buildNewsletter();
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

It runs fine on initialization, but as soon as the window is resized, columnizer creates more "pages" and fills them with redundant content seemly at random.  Can anyone help figure out why this is happening?  If it isn't already obvious, my desired result is a page with fluid columns (meaning the content re-distributes on resize) without the duplicating content problem.  I seem to have gotten the fluid part down, but the extra content is an issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the content is being recolumnized into the same  as the original content. This means that everytime the content is recolumnized, it's only ever adding to the final output, the previous columnized pages are never removed.

A solution is to manually manage that cache of original content, and setup our own recolumnize function when the window is resized.

a jsfiddle with a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Bka8P/

This fiddle puts all of the content into an invisible div:

`<div id="articleBodyCache">`

which columnizes into:

`<div id="articleBody">`

Then we manually empty the articleBody div, and recolumnize when the page is resized. Since we're doing this manually, we also need to set the buildOnce property when columnizing, so that the columnizer onResize listener won't conflict with our own.

```
    $('#articleBody').columnize({
        columns: 2,
        target: ".newsPost:last .content",
        buildOnce: true,
        ...
```